# Titanium studio sdk 6.0,Xaml Node reading issue

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

Titnaium sdk 6.0 ,i used
xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Response"); for reading xaml File. this work in Titnaium sdk 5.5 or lower version of titnaium.

after update SDK 6.0 , xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Response"); this give udefined in Android.

Comment: Did you try with latest version 6.0.4.GA? It's better if you post a full test case.

Comment: yes try ind 6.0.4. but not work.      download rss project from titnaium Github and run.     xml file node get but node value not read. getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).text . always null in sdk 6.0. this work in  lower 6.0 sdk.